# Preventing stack overflows/infinite recursion in user-programmable calculator

Tags: c, recursion, stack-overflow

I wrote a user-programmable calculator, and now I'm hitting the following problem.

Let's say a user writes the following in it:

```
fun(n) = fun(n-1)
```

and then tries to call `fun(42)` (or whatever number). Now obviously, the user's code will cause infinite recursion, which in turn causes the whole calculator to crash with a stack overflow.

How could I make the calculator quit the calculation gracefully?

I have looked at how Mathematica handles similar situations, and it just bails out saying

```
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
```

I have tried a similar approach, but then, as the stack size is OS-dependent, how do I know what number to use as the iteration limit (yes, I found a number that "seems to work" by experimentation, but that doesn't feel right)?

Thanks for your time. The core of the calculator is written in C.

Comment: If you write the calculator to not make recursive calls in the host itself -- e.g. handle the implementation via a stack yourself, then the limit is arbitrary based upon available memory that is/can be allocated (and some "sane depth")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply one of the ugly little corners of C - there's just no portable way to know how much stack you can safely use.  Technically, there doesn't even have to be enough stack to call a single function from `main()` - it's considered a *quality-of-implementation* issue.

The safest approach is to unroll your recursion so that it uses its own expression stack that you allocate with `malloc()`, rather than unbounded genuine recursion.  That way you can bail out if `malloc()` returns `NULL` before you reach your application-defined recursion limit.

Comment: +1 for unrolling the recursion, but if you do so, you should not include a recursion limit; just keep chugging along till malloc fails (or you finish, of course).

Comment: @David X: It might be considered antisocial to spend 30 minutes filling up all the available swap space and finally dying, just because the user gave you some bad input.  The recursion limit is there to catch mistaken infinite recursion (do make it user-tweakable, though).

Comment: right you are, I was thinking hard-coded limit for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing user-level math function calls as C function calls, implement your own heap-based stack with malloc. This will give you a lot more levels of recursion and a way to tell reliably for failure.

Alternatively you could just put a reasonably small limit on levels of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to just keep track of the recursion depth and exit if it is exceeded. A counter will suffice. You may need to reset the counter between each evaluation of course - but it is not as robust as running your own stack.